# MS Dynamics CRM Global Search Getting Related Entities

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I am trying to set up a global search where the user can search by invoice number and it shows the invoice AND related order with OOB solutions.

EDIT
Version: 2015
Unsure of when installed but was updated recently

Comment: What is the version of your CRM? When was it installed/started?

Comment: Not setting up CRM, trying to make the global search find the related order when typing in the invoice number. Must be an out of the box solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global Search works on top of Quick Find view & Find columns specified in particular entities. The searchable entities & its display order can be configured in System settings.

In your scenario, Add the entities Order & Invoice to searchable entities list (move it to top). Then setup the QF view display columns & Find columns (Invoice number) in view of both entities.

[Read more](http://blog.xrm.com/2015/12/07/modifying-global-search-in-crm-online/)

[image]

[image]

Update:
Order can have multiple Invoices associated (Invoice subgrid). Hence Order is a lookup on Invoice. This will make easy to QF with 'Order number' in both entity by 'Order number' field (text in Order, Lookup in Invoice).

But you need to QF 'Invoice number', which is available in Invoice only. You may need to store all the Invoice numbers in a custom field (comma separated) & use it for QF in Order entity.

Comment: Invoice Number is not a field on Order. The order is a field on Invoice