# Customizing Dynamics CRM global search results

Tags: dynamics-crm, customization, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I'm using crm 2016, when I use the search- box (search by text, near the advanced search button) for example: I enter a customer ID and I get all his accounts,Incident etc' in search screen, I need to edit these results, can I do it?
I already tried to edit the views type - 'advanced search' and 'quick search' in my entity (incident) but when I re-search I couldn't see my change, are there any restrictions ?

Comment: well I found it's possible in the views of the selected entity, but I can only have two fields shown in the results (after quick search) can I add more or the limit is two ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Dynamics CRM Global Search Getting Related Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46030951/ms-dynamics-crm-global-search-getting-related-entities)

Comment: @ArunVinoth I didn't look for related entities... so maybe the question is legit,,,

Comment: I just linked the related SO question per guidelines.. not exact dupe I know.

Comment: If it’s worth linking another SO thread, we have to link it instead answering the same query. Asker may upvote if he find it useful. Your OP is having answer from linked post (exact same steps you have to do achieve yours), whereas extended question in comment is extra having answer below. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there’s a limit of 3 left most fields of Quick Find view will be shown.

> When records are displayed in the Global Search results there is a hard limit of only three fields pertaining to the record shown. Those three fields correspond to the 3 left most fields in that entity’s ‘Quick Find’ view. To modify which three fields are shown, you must edit the view and publish.

[Read more](http://ledgeviewpartners.com/blog/global-search-in-dynamics-crm-2015/)